# Core Data object linked to other object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, core-data

I made a "gridView" object that goes coupled with a "gridButton". It does it's thing and allows you to drag button into different view and arrange them as you like.

The problem is that I have an "item" object that come back from core data. I need to basically use the title from all these "items" and put them in buttons.

I've done that and works of course but I need to be able to manipulate the data afterwards by updating it and deleting it. Just having the title of the "item" copied to the "gridButton" means they are not coupled and makes it difficult to manage those types of chores (updates, deletes)

If you guys can point me in the right direction it would really help. I though that maybe I can make the "gridButton" conform to the "item" as a category but I'm not sure how that would work.

I basically need to make it so I can just delete a button with a certain command and it would delete it in core data. How can I link them up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how exactly you have them in the "grid". Do you have a dataSource for them ? If it's like a tableView format, you should check `NSFetchedResultsController` . There the tableView cells are linked to the core-data objects.

Anyhow, as a general suggestion to your problem, this can be done easily. It's just like how you have suggested in your question.

For example, if you need to delete a button, get the `title` from it, and do a `predicateFetch` for that title, and you will be able to find your entity object for that `managedObjectContext`. Simply delete it.

And if you are requiring to assign `title` for your buttons, simply fetch CoreData, and get the required objects, and set the title. These should be fairly simple, as stated in the documentation !

Hope everything is clear :)

Comment: Yeah but if I just assign the "item" title to the "gridButton" I then have to lookup the objectID of the core data "item" and it gets sloppy doing it that way doesn't it? I mean core data doesn't quite work like SQlite... so I thought about making "item" a property of "gridButton" somehow that way I can just delete or update "items" at will then just delete the "gridButton" that doesn't have an "item" associated with it...

Comment: I don't get it. What's wrong with looking up the id for the item you have in the grid. It is the only entity that relates your Core-data and UI stuff. This is how its normally done.

Comment: I thought thought you weren't supposed to do that. That why you have the objects so you can just delete the object itself and core data know what to do. I will do it that way... If I find a better way I will update this...

Comment: @KristianGonzalez When you delete an object, "you can" notify the corresponding delegate methods to find the core-data responsible for it. But you will have to write code to manually delete that core-data for that object. But if you have "relationships" between core-data entities, delting one will also have an effect on other entities as well.

Comment: I ended up adding the "item" as a property of the gridButton when when the gridbutton gets clicked I take that button get the item and delete the item in core data. then I just fade out the empty button in the ui... I really need a better way. I will try to implement delegates for this...